# Both contextmenu/click events fire in Firefox, only contextmenu in Webkit

Tags: javascript

Chrome fires a `contextmenu` event, yet no `click` event for right-clicks. Firefox fires both.

I'm trying to find some official reference or explanation, and I'm surprised I've never come across this yet.

http://jsbin.com/zawifokumu/1/edit?js,console,output

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  console.log('click');
});
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(event) {
  console.log('right click');
});
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  console.log('mousedown');
});
```

Comment: That's fine, but you're not getting `click` which is the issue. Firefox fires all three.

Comment: I don't have an issue dealing with this, I'm trying to find documentation regarding why they do this.

Comment: I find that FF in windows fire events in this order 1)"mousedown" 2)"click" 3)"right click". But FF in macOS fire 1)"mousedown" 2)"right click" 3)"click"

Comment: Just tried in android chrome and the so app. Both events fired.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Firefox people think this is [a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=184051).  But not a very important bug, judging from the fact that it's 14 years old now.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the handler to `document.documentElement` instead.

e.g.

```
 document.documentElement.addEventListener("click", bodyClickHandler);
```